# What transition they use here in their banner and title?

Tags: html, css

What do you call on the transition they use here in this site?

[Please look at this site](https://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/inspiration/23-great-examples-of-innovative-navigation-for-your-inspiration)

[image]

Comment: that's just a fade and parallax effect ( on the text )

Comment: where i can find a tutorial for it?

Comment: check this out: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Background-Parallax-Scrolling-Effect-Fallings.html for parallax. and for fade, you don't need a library, just fade the text on scroll

Answer (score 1):

A simple parallax effect in pure CSS

```css
html,
body {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.background > div {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.background1 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background1);
}

.background2 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background2);
}
.background3 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/800x450&text=Background3);
}
```

```html
<div class="background background1">
    <div>Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="background background2">
    <div>A Second Page</div>
</div>
<div class="background background3">
    <div>A Third Page</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They're just listening to the scroll event, and changing the `position` and the `opacity` of the container element of the title.
You can open up the Inspect Element and see what's exactly happening. `translate(x, x)` and `opacity` property are being changed.

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: @Hamzaouiii it's not helpful for a beginner who's not aware of parallax and  asking for tutorial

Comment: beginner or not, the question was what are they doing to acheive that transition. and the answer as jimosawy said is that they listen to the scrolling event and change position and opacity of the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its called parallax. You can find simple w3schools tutorial below

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

also this can be achieved by variety of js libraries

Comment: How about the soft scrolling image?